# scrollView in react native with pagingEnabled.pages represent variabled length chapter.I want scrollView dynamically adopt height acc. to chap length

Tags: react-native, pagination, scrollview, flatlist

Here is code the code of card render and nested flatlist inside a scrollview
Can some how content of everyschapter has its own height of scroll view (adjust height of scrollview acc. To content)

```
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (

  <View style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width ,backgroundColor:backgroundColorBookRead}}>
  <View style={styles.chapterWrapper}>
    <Text style={styles.contentTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
    <Text style={[styles.chapterContent, { fontSize: fontSizeOfBookRead, fontWeight: fontWeightOfBookRead }]}>{item.content}</Text>
  </View>
</View>
 );


return (
 <ScrollView ref={ref} >
      
     <FlatList
      horizontal
      pagingEnabled
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator{false}
      data={filteredChapters}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      onMomentumScrollEnd={handleMomentumScrollEnd}

      style={styles.contentContainer}
      ref={scrollViewRef}
    />
).
```